# Create Mashable Follow-like Facebook, Twitter login/connect?

Tags: facebook, twitter, authentication, wp-login-form, wp-user-query

Hi want to ask if anyone can share an idea on how [Mashable](http://mashable.com/) registration works? 
Basically the only option you have to register to their site is by Facebook or Twitter, after you login to one of them it automatically create a wp_user. No more Wordpress login/Regs needed.

I know many plugins like *Simple Facebook/Twitter/Google connect <sup>*</sup>* are available, but i haven't found any plugin related to this one like Mashable have. If anyone can help me on this that will be great.

<sub>[*] : [Simple Facebook Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/), [Simple Twitter Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-twitter-connect/), [Simple Google Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-google-connect/) — by Otto</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mashable Follow is custom built for Mashable.com, so you won't find a plugin that brings that level of integration to your WordPress site.

That said, there are two that *may* suit your purpose:

- **[Social](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social/):** Integrates your WordPress site with social networking sites Twitter and Facebook, thereby offering a whole lot of features including—automatically broadcasting posts to the social networks, comment login, pulling in reactions from each (replies, retweets, comments, "likes") as comments, etc.

  This plugin is very well coded, and maintained.
- **[WordPress Social Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-social-login/):** A new plugin in its first public release, supports some 20 social networks. The plugin is built on top of [Social Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social-connect/) plugin and [HybridAuth Library](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Wow WordPress Social Login is so cool! Just some customization and it will be best for my site. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Mashable Follow is custom built and I did not find any plugin that supports this functionality. However, I would like add one more plugin that you might be interested - [Social Login for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/loginradius-for-wordpress/). Other than social login, it also offers user profile data, social analytics and social sharing.

Comment: You need to disclose your relationship to the plugin because it contains possible premium/paid components.